# How ng-content will be using in new release angular v16

Tags: angular

In previous version, ng-content works like this:
`<app-component> <ng-content></ng-content> </app-component>`

But in angular v16, this approach of declaring has changed to `<app-component />`

So, my question is to know how we will be still using ng-content in new approach

I would like to know how we can use ng-content in angular v16

Comment: Where have you seen this code? What angular 16 implements is the self closing tags, but it should be only used when a component has no children...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [release blog](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v16-is-here-4d7a28ec680d#7065), you *can* use self closing tags, but you don't need to. It's just a convenience feature. If you use [content projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection) on a component, you *cannot* use self-closing tags when using this component. So the "old" way of closing the component's tag is still valid and in some cases even necessary.

In your case you cannot use a self-closing tag for the `app-component`, but for the `ng-content`, as the latter doesn't use content projection:

```
<app-component>
  <ng-content />
</app-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Self-closing tags serve as a syntactic shortcut when there is no content enclosed within them.

So in order to use `ng-content`, you should keep the old way

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying, means that the old method will still working??

Comment: @don-delice please have a look at my answer, I explained it there

Comment: Okay i see, i will still using the old method if i want to insert ng-content, THANK YOU !

Comment: Yes, you can still do `<app-component> <ng-content></ng-content> </app-component>` as before